# AS3 TextField doesn't show new text at all even though it's there

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a textfield in a MovieClip that I'm trying to change out from an external class. It appears to return back as empty on the stage, but if I trace what's inside there it gives me the correct value, it just doesn't show up.

My code is this:

```
((this.parent.parent.getChildByName('bottomBar') as MovieClip).getChildByName('area_txt') as TextField).text = 'test';
```

So if I trace "`((this.parent.parent.getChildByName('bottomBar') as MovieClip).getChildByName('area_txt') as TextField).text`" it returns "test" but it doesn't display on the stage, it's just blank.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you have your fonts embedded?

Comment: and is the `this.parent.parent` added to the stage?

Comment: That was it, they weren't embedded for AS. Daniel if you present that as a answer, I'll check it off as the solution.

Comment: lol hate when you get stuck on soemthing you simply forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font needs to be embedded, also a bit of a sidenote if you're using `defaultTextFormat` function you need to call it before setting the text, if you use `setTextFormat` then you do it after

```
textfield.embedFonts          = true;
textfield.defaultTextFormat   = format;          // option 1
textfield.text                = "Hello World";
textfield.setTextFormat (format);                // option 2
```